# How to use the Android Navigation component (Nav Graph) in a Drawer Layout (with navigation drawer Menu)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a navigation graph that uses this fragment as a home in the main activity XML.

```
        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        class="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
```

I have a Drawer layout with a menu , I can't manage to make the navigation to work when I click on the navigation drawer button (it works from main fragment but not when I click on Drawer buttons), If I use the old way to program the navigation drawer using : `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new_fragment).commit();`, my navcontroller is lost!! and I get errors like

> destination fragment in unknown by navcontroller , because the controller will see the home fragment as currently displayed even if it is not the case (from debug)

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_1:
                //doesn't work when it current fragment doesnt match the 
                //action_fromfragmentx_to_fragmenty
                Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.fragment_container)
                .navigate(R.id.action_fromfragmentx_to_fragmenty);
                break;

            //Other menu options...
        }
```

**Hence my question : How should I override this onNavigationItemSelected in Java to make the navigation component work? any link or relative doc about this subject(in Java) ?.**

Comment: have you read this ? https://medium.com/@stavro96/how-to-setup-android-navigation-component-with-drawer-88b833312661

Comment: Hi Yes I was reading it and I couldn't really get the Kotlin code of onOptionsItemSelected since I am not that good with kotlin. That is why I wrote (In Java) on the question

Comment: @John Joe sorry I can't up the project to github. But I do appreciate your Kotlin based article recommendation. could be nice if you have some pointers in Java.

Comment: You don't have to override `onNavigationItemSelected` at all if you're using the `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController()` - that's doing all that work for you by launching the destination with the same ID as your menu item. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you very much for your response (setupWithNavController() didn't know about this function). Well I usually use drawer menu in my App and it is my first time trying to use the Nav Graph utility. It is a small android project (stock and inventory) so I am discovering the NavGraph which is great so far. However I really want to keep the navigation drawer in my app. Anyway Thanks I will try to read more about this setupWithNavController()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Navigation component offers a helper class in [`NavigationUI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.html) in the `navigation-ui` artifact. As per the [Update UI components with Navigation documentation for navigation drawers](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer), you can use the `setupWithNavController()` method to automatically hook up menu items to navigation destinations you set up in your navigation graph by [tying the destination item to a menu item](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer):

> If the id of the `MenuItem` matches the id of the destination, the `NavController` can then navigate to that destination.

Therefore you don't need a `onNavigationItemSelected` implementation at all, nor do you need to do any FragmentTransactions. Just make sure that the `android:id="@+id/fragment_y"` in your menu XML matches the `android:id="@+id/fragment_y"` in your navigation XML and call `setupWithNavController()`:

```
NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
// This is what sets up its own onNavigationItemSelected
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply didn't know that we had something automatic like this  , finally made it work :)